# How to ignore multiple directories and files using electron releoad

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, electron, chokidar

I have an Electron project using electron-reload, the file structure is:

```
./public/templates/ --------- contains some html that should be watched and trigger reload
./public/templates/test/ ---- contains some test/experimental html that should be ignored/not trigger reload
./notes --------------------- just containing some notes, this should not trigger reload
./node_modules -------------- should be ignored
./main.js ------------------- should trigger reload on change
```

I know I can ignore directories by setting the option `ignored` on requiring electron reload in main.js.
This uses chokidar for filtering, ignored option is described [here](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar#path-filtering)

But I don't get how to ignore multiple paths.

I tried to require electron reload like this:

```
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {ignored: /node_modules|notes|public\/templates\/test/gi});
```

But when I change a file in
`public/templates/test/` the application is reloading.

- `electron 5.0.6`
- `electron-reload 1.5.0`

Thanks in advance
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [eletron-reload module](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload#api).

electron_reload(paths, options):

- *paths*: a file, directory or glob pattern to watch
- *options* will default to `{ignored: /node_modules|[\/\\]\./, argv: []}`.

Then in the **ignored** field you put **Regular Expressions** of what you want to ignore. You can check the regular expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

For example, if I want to ignore all the folders: `node_modules`, `files/img`, `resorces` within my directory. The `main.js` would be:

```js
//main.js

const ignoredNode = /node_modules|[/\\]\./;
const ignored1 = /resources|[/\\]\./; // all folder resorces => resources
const ignored2 = /files\/img|[/\\]\./; //all folder files/img => files/img

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {ignored: [ignored1, ignored2, ignoredNode] });   
}
```

This prevents an application `reload` whenever there are changes within the folders: `node_modules`, `files/img`, `resorces`.

Now you have to use `regular expressions` for your purpose.

Comment: Hi @diegodavid,
thanks for the answer, unfortunately it does not work.
I've also tried to ignore only. the test templates by
` const ignoredTestTemplates = /public\/templates\/test|[/\\]\./;

    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {ignored: [ignoredTestTemplates]});`

but the application is still reloading whenever I edit a file in the directory

Comment: Hi @KevinKussmaul I can see that in your code the character "\" is missing. This must be inside the brackets `[/ \\]`, note that there are two "\". Your code should be as follows: `const ignoredTestTemplates = /public\/templates\/test|[/\\]\./;  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){ require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {ignored: [ignoredTestTemplates] }); }`

Comment: Also note what is your `__dirname`, if the `public` folder is inside or outside of your project. This code is used when the `public` folder is inside your project.

Comment: Tested this again on a new machine, with new electron and node installations (node v20.2.0, electron 24.0.0, electron-reload 2.0.0-alpha.1) => did not work on my machine ... 
I switched to nodemon. Adding a nodemon.json file at project root folder like this  
`{
  "ignoreRoot": ["node_modules", "notes", ".git", "public/templates/test"],
  "ignore": [".gitignore", "*.db", "package-lock.json"],
  "ext": "js, json, html, less, css"
}`
Now I execute `nodemon --exec electron .` instead of `electron .`
This is a solution that works for me.